# Maatwebsite descarga archivos excel dañados

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

Estoy trabajando con la librería [Maatwebsite 3.1](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/), pero al descargar los archivos **.xlsx** se descargan dañados.

Me gustaria saber si se podía corregir ese error ya que los requerimientos están bien.

[image: Ejemplo de documento dañado]

Controlador:

```
class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $users = User::all();
        return view('export_excel', compact('users'));
    }

    public function export(){
        return Excel::download(new UsuarioExport(), 'usuarios.xls');
    }
}
```

Exportación:

```
class UsuarioExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo creo que esa biblioteca de funciones genera un archivo xlsx por defecto y tú estás generando la descarga de un xls. Son formatos diferentes. ¿Has probado a cambiar la extensión y configurar `'usuarios.xlsx'` como archivo de descarga en vez de `'usuarios.xls'`?

Comment: si, ya lo probé en los .xlsx pero de igual forma no me abre el archivo

Comment: ¿Has probado a indicar explícitamente el tipo? Es decir, `return Excel::download('usuarios.xls', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLS)`. Si sigue sin funcionar, ¿podrías compartir el archivo en alguna plataforma como drive, mega, etc para poder ver si hay "caracteres extras"?

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XzpnS5UFOoi2gd6Ibh58YCP1axxau82F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Drive me dice que no has compartido el archivo públicamente, así que te he requerido acceso a él.

Comment: ya lo puse publico

Comment: Para buscar el error, es mejor que [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108440/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-sandra-olivares-miramontes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tras recibir una copia del archivo generado encuentro un retorno del carro y nueva línea al comienzo del archivo XLSX:

```
00000000  0d 0a 50 4b 03 04 14 00  02 00 08 00 af 08 b9 50  |..PK...........P|
00000010  47 92 44 b2 58 01 00 00  f0 04 00 00 13 00 00 00  |G.D.X...........|
```

Lo que indica que:

- Algún PHP cargado está empezando por una línea en blanco antes de la apertura de PHP (`<?php`).
- Algún archivo PHP está cerrando la etiqueta de PHP (`?>`) junto con una nueva línea adicional al final. [PSR-2 recomienda no cerrar PHP si el archivo contiene únicamente código](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#22-files) precisamente para evitar este problema.

Si existe dificultad para encontrar el origen de esos caracteres adicionales extras, existe una ñapa (workaround) que consiste en activar [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/ob_start) al comienzo del primer PHP cargado y posteriormente, antes de generar el excel, vaciar el contenido del búfer con [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_end_clean).

Archivo `route.php`:

```
<?php
/* Activamos el almacenamiento en búfer */
ob_start();

use App\Http\Controllers\Registro\RegistroController;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

Auth::routes();
/* ... */
```

Archivo `UsuarioController.php`:

```
class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('export_excel', compact('users'));
    }

    public function export() {
        /* Desechamos cualquier contenido generado previamente */
        ob_end_clean();
        return Excel::download(new UsuarioExport(), 'usuarios.xls');
    }
}
```

NOTA: Cuando recibí el archivo `route.php` pude ver que era el culpable, ya que era el que contenía el retorno del carro antes de abrir `<?php`:

```
00000000  0d 0a 3c 3f 70 68 70 0d  0a 0d 0a 75 73 65 20 41  |..<?php....use A|
00000010  70 70 5c 48 74 74 70 5c  43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 6c  |pp\Http\Controll|
```